# Android studio generates wrong kotlin package

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

Kotlin is enabled in my android project.
Also, I added Kotlin source path:

```
sourceSets {
    main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
}
```

When Kotlin class is created in the java folder it has correct package:

```
package com.example
```

When Kotlin class is created in Kotlin folder it has incorrect package:

```
package com.example.com.example
```

How can I fix that?

Android stuido version:

```
Android Studio 3.2.1
Build #AI-181.5540.7.32.5056338, built on October 9, 2018
JRE: 1.8.0_152-release-1136-b06 amd64
JVM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o
Windows 10 10.0
```

Comment: Could you post a snippet of your AndroidManifest file? it contains fields related to package path/name

Comment: @EamonScullion thank you for your interest. But the problem was with wrong file location... You can check it below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was in one Kotlin class outside package:

```
src/kotlin
----------com/example
---------------------Test.kt
----------BadClass.kt
```

BadClass.kt:

```
package com.example

class BadClass
```

When I moved it to the correct directory the problem disappeared:

```
src/kotlin
----------com/example
---------------------Test.kt
---------------------BadClass.kt
```